# Accessing clicked element and "this" class reference in the same scope

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this piece of code written in coffeescript (sorry..)

```
_this = this
$('body').on 'click', '.open-modal', =>
    _this.modalId = $(this).attr('data-modal-id')
    _this.modalEl = $( '#' + _this.modalId )
    _this.modalAction = $(this).attr('data-action')

    _this.openModal()
```

is there a way how to access clicked element `('.open-modal')` and in the same time preserving `this` keyword for the Class not the clicked element.

basically I would want to achieve something like this

```
$('body').on 'click', '.open-modal', (el) =>
    this.modalId = $(el).attr('data-modal-id')
    this.modalEl = $( '#' + this.modalId )
    this.modalAction = $(el).attr('data-action')

    this.openModal()
```

is there a way how to do it?

Comment: what's wrong with the first way?

Comment: nothing much I just don't like how it looks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ECMAScript 6, the arrow function syntax (`() => {}`) does this, though you'll have to get the element from the event object. I think CoffeeScript might convert it's `() => {}` syntax to ES5 version of a function and may not do this (I think it depends on your compiler settings).

```
$('body').on('click', '.open-modal', (evt) => {
    this.modalId = $(evt.target).attr('data-modal-id');
    this.modalEl = $('#' + this.modalId);
    this.modalAction = $(evt.target).attr('data-action');
});
```

If you can't use that, the common pattern is to save `this` as `self` and then use that in other scopes. This doesn't rely on any specific compiler help.

```
var self = this;
$('body').on('click', '.open-modal', function () {
    this.modalId = $(this).attr('data-modal-id')
    this.modalEl = $('#' + self.modalId)
    this.modalAction = $(this).attr('data-action')
});
```

Finally, if you really want it exactly as you have it, you can wrap the callback in another function that sets things up as you want.

```
$('body').on('click', '.open-modal', (function (self) {
    return function () { 
        (function (el) {
            this.modalId = $(el).attr('data-modal-id');
            this.modalEl = $('#' + this.modalId);
            this.modalAction = $(el).attr('data-action');
        }).call(self, this);
    };
})(this));
```

Though that's a bit silly and overkill. It uses a self-calling function to scope the this to self, returns a function, which then wraps another that uses `call` to specify `this` and pass in the element as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It helped me to clarify my thoughts about this part of javascript